# How to check if record exist in sqlite, if yes, then update it.?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

first of all i'm describing some explanation about my question,
i have two fragments name as "Main Fragment" and second one is " Cart Fragment"

1==> Main Fragment- Contains recyclerview in which data comes from firestore and set in recyclerview, when user click on add or remove button then data is entered and update in sqlite.

2==> Cart Fragment- Contains recyclerview in which data comes from SQLITE and set in recycelerview.

My Question is when i navigate from cart fragment to Main Fragment then First check that any item is already saved in sqlite or not, if exist then get total item quantity from cart fragment of that item(including other data like name, price etc.) and set in main fragmnet.

Here code for Main Fragment Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.TV_OFF.setText(_mylistdata.get(position).getDiscount()+"% OFF");
   //"Rs "+
    holder.TV_CURNT_PRICE.setText(_mylistdata.get(position).getCurr_price());
    holder.TV_OLD_PRICE.setText(_mylistdata.get(position).getOld_price());
    holder.TV_NAME.setText(_mylistdata.get(position).getName());
    holder.TV_OFFER_DES.setText(_mylistdata.get(position).getOffers_des());
    holder.TV_UNIT.setText(_mylistdata.get(position).getUnit_products()+" Unit");
    Picasso.get().load(_mylistdata.get(position).getImgId()).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image_find).into(holder.imageView);


    holder.add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Toast.makeText(context, "pos="+prd_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.add_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.TV_REMOVEITEM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.TV_TOTALITEM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.TV_ADDITEM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            count_value=1;

            holder.TV_TOTALITEM.setText(Integer.toString(count_value));
            // get data from views
            getDataFromViews(position);
            total_qty_pro= (String) holder.TV_TOTALITEM.getText();
            //qty_pro=_mylistdata.get(position).getUnit_products();
            qty_new=qty_pro+" Unit";
            saveData_To_SQLITE(new_name,qty_new,price_pro,price_old,total_qty_pro,image_id,context);

        }

    });
    holder.TV_REMOVEITEM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //productId= (int) getItemId(position);
            count_value--;
            if (count_value<1)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"Remove button is pressed");
                holder.add_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.TV_REMOVEITEM.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.TV_TOTALITEM.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.TV_ADDITEM.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                count_value=1;

                String prdct_name= _mylistdata.get(position).getName();

                delete_record(prdct_name,context);

            }else {
                //Data_parsing.setCountText(count_value);
                holder.TV_TOTALITEM.setText(Integer.toString(count_value));

                total_qty_pro= (String) holder.TV_TOTALITEM.getText();
                String prdct_name= _mylistdata.get(position).getName();

                UPDATE_SQL_DATA(prdct_name,total_qty_pro,context);

            }

        }
    });
    holder.TV_ADDITEM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Add button is pressed");
            count_value++;
            //Data_parsing.setCountText(count_value);
            holder.TV_TOTALITEM.setText(Integer.toString(count_value));

            total_qty_pro= (String) holder.TV_TOTALITEM.getText();
            String prdct_name= _mylistdata.get(position).getName();
            UPDATE_SQL_DATA(prdct_name,total_qty_pro,context);
        }


    });
}
```

Here is my SQLite class in which i define my static methods for saving, updating and delete my data from sqlite

public class SQLITE_RUD {

```
// Save data to sqlite
public static void  saveData_To_SQLITE(String name_pro, String qty_pro, String price_pro,String price_old, String total_qty_pro, String image_id, Context context) {
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(context);
    db.openDB();
    long result =  db.add(name_pro, qty_pro, price_pro,price_old, total_qty_pro, image_id);
    if (result > 0) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Data is saved succeffuly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    db.closeDB();
}

// update data in sqlite

public static void UPDATE_SQL_DATA(String p_name, String total_qty_pro, Context context)
{
    DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(context);
    db.openDB();
    try {
        long result=db.update_DB(p_name,total_qty_pro);
        if(result>0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Updated Sucesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("MyListAdapter","error_update="+e);
    }
    db.closeDB();
}
// Delete data from SQlite
public static void delete_record(String prdct_name,Context context) {
    //
    DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(context);
    db.openDB();
    try {
        long result=db.Delete_DB(prdct_name);
        if(result>0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted Sucesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("MyListAdapter","error_delete="+e);
    }
    db.closeDB();
}
```

}

Here i create class name ad DBAdapter in which i define methods for saving, updating, and retriving quires.

```
public class DBAdapter {
Context c;
SQLiteDatabase db;
DbHelper database_helper;   // on create and on upgrade is defined

public DBAdapter(Context c) {
    this.c = c;
    database_helper=new DbHelper(c);

}

//OPEN DB
public void openDB()
{
    try {
        db=database_helper.getWritableDatabase();
        db=database_helper.getReadableDatabase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//CLOSE DB
public void closeDB()
{
    try {
        database_helper.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//INSERT/SAVE
public long add(String P_name,String P_qty,String P_price,String P_OldPrice,String P_Total_qty, String P_Image)
{
    try {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        // cv.put(KEY_ItemID, P_id);
        cv.put(KEY_ProductName, P_name);
        cv.put(KEY_ProductQuantity, P_qty);
        cv.put(KEY_ProductPrice, P_price);
        cv.put(KEY_OldPrice, P_OldPrice);
        cv.put(KEY_ProductTotal, P_Total_qty);
        cv.put(KEY_ProductImage,P_Image);
        return db.insert(Table_name, KEY_RowID, cv);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
public long update_DB(String name_prdct, String prdct_TOTAL_QTY)
{
    try
    {
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ProductTotal,prdct_TOTAL_QTY);
        return db.update(Table_name,cv,KEY_ProductName +" =?",new String[]{String.valueOf(name_prdct)});
        //return;
    }catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}

//DELETE
public long Delete_DB(String prdct_name)
{
    try
    {
        return db.delete(Table_name,KEY_ProductName+" =?",new String[]{String.valueOf(prdct_name)});

    }catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}

//SELECT/RETRIEVE
public Cursor retrieve() {
    String[] columns = {KEY_RowID,KEY_ProductName,KEY_ProductQuantity, KEY_ProductPrice,KEY_OldPrice, KEY_ProductTotal, KEY_ProductImage};
    return db.query(Constants.Table_name, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

}

Here is my Cart Fragment

```
public class CartFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String Tag ="CartFragment" ;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RelativeLayout proceedBtn;
TextView finalprice_bottom, finalprice_upper;
Adapter_chart adapter;
View view;
ArrayList<Chart_getter_setter> chartGetterSetters = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.chart_recyclerview);
    proceedBtn=view.findViewById(R.id.bottomChart);

    finalprice_upper=view.findViewById(R.id.price);
    finalprice_bottom =view.findViewById(R.id.FinalPrice_TV);
    proceedBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(savedInstanceState==null) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, ProceedFragment.newInstance()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        }
    });

    adapter = new Adapter_chart(getActivity(), fragmentManager, chartGetterSetters);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //RETRIEVE
    retrieve_data();

    getActivity().setTitle("Final chart");

    return view;
}
private void retrieve_data() {
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getContext());
    db.openDB();
    chartGetterSetters.clear();
    //RETRIEVE
    Cursor c = db.retrieve();
    while (c.moveToNext())
    {
        int index_id=c.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_RowID);
        int index_name=c.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ProductName);
        int index_qty=c.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ProductQuantity);
        int index_price=c.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ProductPrice);
        int index_oldprice=c.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_OldPrice);
        int index_total=c.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ProductTotal);
        int index_image=c.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ProductImage);

        int id=c.getInt(index_id);
        String name=c.getString(index_name);
        String qty=c.getString(index_qty);
        String price=c.getString(index_price);
        String oldPrice=c.getString(index_oldprice);
        String total=c.getString(index_total);
        String IMAGE=c.getString(index_image);


        Chart_getter_setter p=new Chart_getter_setter(name,qty,price,oldPrice,total,IMAGE);
        //ADD TO ARRAYLIS
        chartGetterSetters.add(p);

        //CHECK IF ARRAYLIST ISNT EMPTY

        if(chartGetterSetters.size()>0)
        {
            int totalPrice = 0;
            int total_qty=0;
            for(int j = 0 ; j < chartGetterSetters.size(); j++) {

                totalPrice += Integer.parseInt(chartGetterSetters.get(j).getPrice_prdct())*Integer.parseInt(chartGetterSetters.get(j).getTotal_quantity()) ;
                total_qty += Integer.parseInt(chartGetterSetters.get(j).getTotal_quantity());
            }
            String tProice=String.valueOf(totalPrice);
            finalprice_upper.setText("Rs "+tProice);
            finalprice_bottom.setText(String.valueOf(total_qty));//totelPriceTV.setText(tProice);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my Adapter Cart

```
public class Adapter_chart extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder_chart> {
private static final String TAG ="Adapater_chart" ;
ArrayList<Chart_getter_setter> _chartdata;
Context context;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
String total = "";

public Adapter_chart(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, 
    ArrayList<Chart_getter_setter> _chartdata) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    this._chartdata = _chartdata;

    _chartdata = new ArrayList<>();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder_chart onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chart_single_item, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder_chart viewHolder = new ViewHolder_chart(view);
    return viewHolder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder_chart viewHolder_chart, final int i) {

    viewHolder_chart.p_name_CHART_tv.setText(_chartdata.get(i).getName_prdct()); // set name of product
    //Replace these two methods
    viewHolder_chart.p_price_CHART_tv.setText(_chartdata.get(i).getPrice_prdct());  // set quantity
    viewHolder_chart.p_quantity_Chart_tv.setText(_chartdata.get(i).getUnit_prdct());  // set price
    ////////////////////////////////
    viewHolder_chart.p_totalITem_CHART_tv.setText(_chartdata.get(i).getTotal_quantity());

    Log.d("Adapter_chart", "bitmap=" + _chartdata.get(i).getImage_prdct());
    //viewHolder_chart.p_img_CHART.setImageBitmap(_chartdata.get(i).getImage_prdct());
    Picasso.get().load(_chartdata.get(i).getImage_prdct()).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image_find).into(viewHolder_chart.p_img_CHART);

    viewHolder_chart.p_add_CHART_tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Add button is pressed");
            int count_value= Integer.parseInt((String) viewHolder_chart.p_totalITem_CHART_tv.getText());

            count_value++;
            viewHolder_chart.p_totalITem_CHART_tv.setText(Integer.toString(count_value));

            String total_qty_pro= (String) viewHolder_chart.p_totalITem_CHART_tv.getText();
            String prdct_name= (String) _chartdata.get(i).getName_prdct();
            UPDATE_SQL_DATA(prdct_name,total_qty_pro,context);


        }
    });
    viewHolder_chart.p_remove_CHART_tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int count_value= Integer.parseInt((String) viewHolder_chart.p_totalITem_CHART_tv.getText());
            count_value--;
            if (count_value<1)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"Remove button is pressed");

                String name_prdct= (String) viewHolder_chart.p_name_CHART_tv.getText();
                delete_record(name_prdct,context);
                _chartdata.remove(i);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }else {
                viewHolder_chart.p_totalITem_CHART_tv.setText(Integer.toString(count_value));
                String total_qty_pro= (String) viewHolder_chart.p_totalITem_CHART_tv.getText();
                String prdct_name= (String) _chartdata.get(i).getName_prdct();
                UPDATE_SQL_DATA(prdct_name,total_qty_pro,context);

            }
        }


    viewHolder_chart.item_remove_imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name_prdct= (String) viewHolder_chart.p_name_CHART_tv.getText();
            delete_record(name_prdct,context);
            _chartdata.remove(i);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return _chartdata.size();
}
```

}

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMEcN.jpg

Comment: The question is unclear for me, but I think you can use WHERE Clause in your SQLite statement. For example UPDATE Users SET weight = 160, desiredWeight = 145 WHERE id = 1;

Comment: No sir, i want to check that if record is saved in sqlite(which display in cart fragment ), when i move from cart fragment to main fragment then first check that items are saved already or not , if yes , retrive saved order quantity and paste in main fragment order quantity textview.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite replace statement is for you.

REPLACE INTO table_name ( col1, col2 ) VALUES ( val1, val2 );

Replace will either
-- insert into db if not exist
-- update db if already exist

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by using Room with LiveData. With these components, you will get updated values when you add, remove or even edit a row in the database table. You can learn these components from here. [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) - [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) also you can read this [google codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#0).
But if you don't want to use these components(I highly recommend you to use them) I think you can get all rows in your database in your activity onResum() method and update your RecyclerView with new data.